# 8th degree polynomial has 16 complex roots?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Asked to find roots of the equation $z^8 + (5/2)z^4 + 1 = 0$. Using the quadratic equation gives $z^4 = 2, 1/2$. I also found that if $w$ is a root of the equation, then $iw$ and $1/w$ are also roots.

By factoring $P(z)$ into $(z^4 - 2)(z^4 - 1/2)$, I found that the roots must be:

$$
\begin{split}
&\pm \sqrt[4]{2}\\
&\pm i\sqrt[4]{2}\\
&\pm 1/\sqrt[4]{2}\\
&\pm i/\sqrt[4]{2}\\
&\pm \sqrt[4]{1/2}\\
&\pm i\sqrt[4]{1/2}\\
&\pm 1/\sqrt[4]{1/2}\\
&\pm i/\sqrt[4]{1/2}\\
\end{split}
$$

How can this degree $8$ polynomial have $16$ complex roots?

Comment: $1/2^{1/4} = (1/2)^{1/4}.$

Comment: you have an error, actually $z^4 = -2, -\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Your are double counting and don't know that those roots can't be expressed in two different ways.  And actually as we *know* it can't have more than eight roots, that must be the case.  Any was $\frac 1{\sqrt[4]{\frac 12}} = \sqrt[4]2$ so only the first four of your list are distinct.

Comment: Actually I'm sure how you got those roots.  TO find the roots of $x^4-2$, I'd figure we have $x=\pm \sqrt[4]2$ and $x=\pm i\sqrt[4]2$ and to find the roots of $x^4-\frac 12$ I'd figure $x =\pm \sqrt[4]{\frac 12}; x=\pm i\sqrt[4]{\frac 12}$ and then I'd stop as there is no-where further to go.  How did you get the 16$.  (And let's not forget Will Jagy's observation)

Answer (score 2):

Using your factorization, then finding the roots for each of the two factors give:

$$\left\{-\sqrt[4]{-2},\frac{1-i}{\sqrt[4]{2}},i
   \sqrt[4]{-2},\sqrt[4]{-2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}},-\frac{i}{\sqrt[4]{2}},\frac{i}{\sqrt
   [4]{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\right\}$$

Of course, only $8$ roots.

Comment: the actual values of $z^4 = -2, -\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how you factored?

You made an error that $z^8 + \frac 52 z^4 + 1=(z^4+2)(z^4 + \frac 12)$ but that's not a serious error that will give you $16$ solutions.  I'm going to solve $P(z)=z^8 - \frac 52 z^4 + 1$ to match your work.

So $P(z) = (x^4 -2)(x^4 -\frac 12)=$
$(x^2 -\sqrt 2)(x^2 + \sqrt 2)(x^2 -\sqrt{\frac 12})(x^2 +\sqrt{\frac 12})=$
$(x-\sqrt[4]2)(x+\sqrt[4]2)(x-i\sqrt[4]2)(x+i\sqrt[4]2)(x-\sqrt[4]{\frac 12})(x+\sqrt[4]{\frac 12})(x-i\sqrt[4]{\frac 12})(x+i\sqrt[4]{\frac 12})$

And $8$ solutions $\pm \sqrt[4]2;\pm i\sqrt[4]2; \pm \sqrt[4]{\frac 12};\pm i\sqrt[4]{\frac 12}$.

How did you get the extra terms?  (Which as $\frac 1{\frac 1a} = a$ are actually all duplicates anyway.)

Anyway for $Q(z) =z^8 + \frac 52 x^4 + 1 = (x^4+2)(x^4 + \frac 12)$ we must actually find the four roots of $-2$ and the four roots of $-\frac 12$.

To solve $w^4 = -1$ we have $w^2 = \pm i$ and to solve $w^2 = i$ we have $\frac \pm(\frac1{\sqrt 2} + i\frac 1{\sqrt 2})=\pm \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \pm \frac1{\sqrt 2}$ and to have $w^2=-i$ we have $\pm i(\frac 1{\sqrt 2} + i\frac 1{\sqrt 2}) =\pm \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\mp i\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.

So to have $z^4=-2$ or $z^4 = -\frac 14$ we take those $4$ results and multiply them but $\sqrt[4]2$ and $\sqrt[4]{\frac 12}$.